# TensorFlow Error: "Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or dir

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, yolo

I am trying to use a repository I found on GitHub (https://github.com/AntonMu/TrainYourOwnYOLO) to train a YOLO model for a text detection application. However, when running one of the provided scripts to download and convert YOLO weights, I get the following errors [screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jiGZ.png)

I know that the issue is that I am missing libraries, however I am not having much success finding/downloading those libraries.

So far I have tried running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

I have also tried running:

```
sudo find / -name 'libcudart.so*'
```

However, I am getting a 'Permission Denied' Message

I was going to try the advice listed on this blog: https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2021/08/how-to-install-cuda-11-on-ubuntu-2004.html
However, I am very new to doing projects like this and am worried about running commands that will mess with my computer...is this a safe/correct solution?

If anybody could offer any other recommendations, I would greatly appreciate it. (OR if you know of any simpler methods of running YOLO on images tagged with VoTT) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check version TensorFlow, Cuda and Cudnn is correctly matching.
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source